# How to remove images stored in access (.accdb)?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to keep access database size to a minimum and need to remove several large images that previously were used but now aren't needed. My understanding is access  files (.accdb) store images inside the database. Do you know if it's possible to remove it and how? TIA

clarification & solution: I had several different forms with different background images, however at this point I have figured it out (for Access 2013) -> under Form Design Tools -> Design -> Insert Image, then right click on the image you need to remove and then click on Delete. Done.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: Are you talking about images stored in a `OLE Object` field of an Access table? Do you need to save those images as separate files, or are you content to simply delete them from the database? Also, does the term "several" imply that it might be feasible to remove them manually?

Comment: Thanks Gord, your questions helped me find a solution. I've added it to the question body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make it easier for anyone else looking for this answer, here is a screen shot of what this looks like in Microsoft Access 2010:

[image]

Comment: This shows some but not all of the images embedded in the Access file I'm currently working on - not sure how to clear out the rest!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely remove all shared pictures in the database, or ones whose name matches a certain pattern you can do something like this:

```
Sub PurgeSharedImages(Optional strPattern As String = "*")
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = CurrentProject.Resources.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If CurrentProject.Resources(i).Type = 1 And CurrentProject.Resources(i).Name Like strPattern Then 
      CurrentProject.Resources(i).Delete
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```